# How do I remove /etc/nologin

Tags: terminal, filesystem, login

I was perusing man pages for fun, as I often do when bored, and happened to be playing around with `login` today. The `login` man page mentioned that creating a `/etc/nologin` file would prevent a user from logging in. I decided to try it.

The good new is it works as advertised. The bad news is I can no longer use the Terminal. I can't remove the file with `rm` for obvious reasons, and I can't even delete it from Finder because I can't see hidden files.

How do I regain control of my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Power down the system (using the standard Shut Down in the Apple menu) and then start it up again. Shutdown should remove the nologin file for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another admin user on that Mac you can open a shell as that user and rely on `sudo`.  If not, boot to single user mode and remove the file.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573

Comment: `/etc/nologin` works for all users, using another one won't help